# Hide Meta banner on the Enter the Private Beta page

Tags: feature-request, per-site-meta, private-beta, notification-bar

The "Enter the Private Beta" page (visible if you open https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/ in a private window, or in a regular window if you haven't joined yet) contains a banner notifying you of the existence of the meta site. However, if you click that link, you're not actually going to the meta site; you end up on the same page. (Only when you log in, you'll notice the difference.) I think it's better not to show that banner on that page at all.

[image]